# How to install programs? Keep getting archive manger error

Tags: software-installation

When trying to download and install programs keep getting archive manger error. Need to be able to install CCLEANER

Comment: What program like CCLEANER will work on Ubuntu?

Comment: To install software see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware . Programs such as ccleaner are not needed with Linux

Comment: @Devildog47906 does the problem **archive manager error** is only with the **CCleaner** or with any package you install.

Comment: Have only tried CCLEANER so far

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [Ubuntu Tweak](http://www.unixmen.com/after-a-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat-configuration-made-easy-with-ubuntu-tweak/). It has a built-in cleaning function which might do what you want.